# ADFS 3.0 Error Event IDs 273 and 364 on windows 2012 r2

Tags: saml-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I am currently working on creating a custom MFA for my company to use to log in to a windows machine. I found the examples provided through two different blogs, but when I try to login using the second authentication method, I get back the following errors**(https:// removed from all links due to reputation limits)**:

---

**273:**The request specified an assertion consumer service  that is not  configured or not supported on the relying party 'domain/adfs/ls/'.
Request parameters: '', '', ''
Relying party: domain/adfs/ls/

This request failed.

User Action
Use the AD FS Management snap-in to configure an assertion consumer service with the specified parameters for this relying party. Also, check whether the artifact resolution service is enabled if the SAML artifact is requested.

I have made sure that adfs/ls/ is enabled, and is listed as an identifier in the relying party trust

---

**364:** Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name:
Saml

Relying Party:
domain/adfs/ls/

Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine.AssertionConsumerServiceNotFoundPolicyException: MSIS3110: Cannot find AssertionConsumerService configured on the relying party trust 'domain/adfs/ls/' that matches the request parameters: AssertionConsumerServiceIndex=, AssertionConsumerServiceUrl='', ProtocolBinding=''.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

---

I have tried to add additional claim methods and adjust the federated services identifier URL. I have also tried manually setting up the relying party trust as well as using the Federation xml.

I know that Error ID 364 tends to be generic, covering many different things, but it typically goes along with the second errors that I get when trying different fixes. However, I always find myself back here.

Here is the custom MFA that I followed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn783423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I also compared with this one: http://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2014/02/01/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-on-windows-server-2012-r2-part-2/

---

I am new to servers, so it's possible that something is set up wrong in that. However, the only warning that I am still getting is about the UPN (event ID 415): The SSL certificate does not contain all UPN suffix values that exist in the enterprise.  Users with UPN suffix values not represented in the certificate will not be able to Workplace-Join their devices.

Any guidance as to what to try next would be much appreciated.